# on click confirm inside php echo

Tags: javascript, php

i want to be able to confirm any deletes of the mysql database before the query is executed. i checked online and found that i need to use `on click` using `confirm` javascript code when specifying the link.

i have the following code which runs while a mysql qry is being run

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='if(confirm(\"Are you sure you want to do this?\")) location.href=country.php?delete&id=".$row['id']."'>delete</a></td>";
```

the country.php?delete&id=x basically runs an `isset` and `_get` to define the id as a variable and delete the corresponding record. this works fine, just need the confirm to work. ideally i wanted it to not be embedded in the link but during the `isset` `_get`

i know there is a syntax or punctuation error somewhere but not able to tackle it.

Comment: onclick="return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to do      this?\")...

Comment: doesn't change anything. sorry

Comment: You're missing a quote after location.href=

Comment: @codeaddict due it being php echo, if i add a quote it throws a syntax error. i tried also \" but same issue. i think the solution is something to do with the quotes but they need to be strategically placed so the .$row['id']. gets properly escaped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using location.href to do the redirect, you could just put the link in the href. If they click OK it will redirect them.

Something like this.

```
echo "<td><a href='country.php?delete&id=".$row['id']."' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to do this?\")'>delete</a></td>";
```

Edit: typos

Comment: this brings the dialogue box, but whether i press ok or cancel, it executes the delete code. this is not the desired effect. if i press cancel, it should return